# How do i edit registered users information via PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Am not sure how to ask this question but for most of you more experienced php programmers this is going to sound trivial... So I have successfully set up a register and login system and also an admin section where the administrator can see all the users that are currently registered. What I am wanting is for the admin to be able to edit the user's details, and also have the capability to delete/block them. Actually I have just successfully implemented a delete function.

This code here is of the page where the admin can see the users:

```
<?php
require('admin_sessions.php');
require("../includes/dbconnect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Admin - iTrade Users Details</title>
<meta name="robots" content="NOFOLLOW,NOINDEX">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ie7.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>

<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ie8.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>

<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
table{
border:1px solid black;
width:2508px;
}
table th{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
border-left:1px solid black;
border-top:1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
}
.header_tables{
background-color:black;
color:white;
text-align:center
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<header style="width:2570px;"><span class="header_img"><img src="../img/itradeheader.png" width="465" height="200" alt="iTrade - The Leading Online Trading Portal"></span></header>
<nav style="width:2470px;">
<ul>

<li><p><a href="../index.php">Home</a></p></li>
<li><p><a href="../aboutitrade.php">About iTrade</a></p></li>
<li><p><a href="../browseauctions.php">Browse Auctions</a></p></li>
<li><p><a href="#">F.A.Q's</a></p></li>
<li><p><a href="../support.php">Support</a></p></li>
<?php if($_SESSION['authorisation'] != 'knownuser'){
echo("<li class=\"spacer\"><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"../login.php\">User Log In</a></p></li><li><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"../register.php\">User Register</a></p></li>");
}
else{
echo("<li class=\"spacer\"><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"../logout.php\">User Logout</a></p></li>");
$loggedin = "<p>You are logged in.</p>";
}

if($_SESSION['authorisation'] != 'known_admin_user'){
echo("<li><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"index.php\">Admin</a></p></li>");
}
else{
echo("<li><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"index.php\">Admin</a></p></li><li><p class=\"loginlogoutregister\"><a href=\"admin_logout.php\">Admin Logout</a></p></li>");
}
?>
</ul>
</nav>

<article style="width:2550px; height:100%;">
<h1>Admin - iTrade Users Details</h1>

<p><a href="index.php">&laquo; Back to main admin page</a></p>

<ul>
<li>Users on iTrade</li>
<li><a href="itradeadminusers.php" title="Admin Users on iTrade">Admin Users on iTrade</a></li>
<li><a href="adminregister.php" title="Register a New Admin User">Register a New Admin User</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Here is a table containing details about the currently registered users on iTrade:</p>

<fieldset style="width:2480px; height:100%; margin:0 auto;">
<legend style="font-size:30px; color:#000000; background-color:inherit;">A record of users on iTrade</legend>
<table>
<tr class="header_tables">
<th><u>User I.D</u></th>
<th><u>User Level</u></th>
<th><u>User-name</u></th>
<th><u>First Name</u></th>
<th><u>Last Name</u></th>
<th><u>Email</u></th>
<th><u>Password</u></th>
<th><u>Gender</u></th>
<th><u>Birthday</u></th>
<th><u>Landline Number</u></th>
<th><u>Mobile Number</u></th>
<th><u>Street Address</u></th>
<th><u>Suburb</u></th>
<th><u>City/Town</u></th>
<th><u>Province</u></th>
<th><u>Postcode</u></th>
<th><u>Closest Town</u></th>
<th><u>Confirmed?</u></th>
<th><u>Date Registered</u></th>
</tr>
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_list;";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$users_on_itrade = " ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo("<tr>");
echo('<td>' . $row['user_id'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['user_level'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['user_username'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['user_email'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['user_pass'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['gender']. '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['birthdate_day'] . $row['birthdate_month'] . $row['birthdate_year'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['phoneNumber'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['mobileNumber'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['addressline1'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['addressline2'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['addressline3'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['stateprovince'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['postcode'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['closest_town'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['confirmed'] . '</td>');
echo('<td>' . $row['user_date'] . '</td>');
echo('<td><a href="edit.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Edit</a></td>');
echo('<td><a href="delete.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Delete</a></td>');
echo("<tr>");
}

?>
</table>
</fieldset>

</article>

<footer style="width:2550px;"><p>&copy; Copyright 2011 iTrade LTD. Website design and development by <a href="http://www.interkiwiwebdevelopers.com" onClick="target='_blank'" title="InterKiwi Web Developers">InterKiwi Web Developers</a>. Special thanks to the <a href="http://cs.otago.ac.nz" onClick="target='_blank'" title="The Computer Science dept at the University of Otago">Computer Science department</a> at the University of Otago, and the lecturers and lab administrators/demonstrators of the universities' <a href="http://cs.otago.ac.nz/comp212" onClick="target='_blank'" title="The Advanced Web Development paper, taught by the Computer Science dept at the University of Otago">Advanced Web Development</a> paper.</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is for the "edit" page link in "`<td><a href="edit.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Edit</a></td>`":

```
<?php
require('admin_sessions.php');
require("../includes/dbconnect.php");
require('../includes/itradeuser.php');
?>
<?php
/* 
This php script allows the administrator to edit a specific itrade user in the database.
*/

// creates the edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($user_id, $user_email, $user_pass, $user_pass_confirm, $user_username, $firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthdate_day, $birthdate_month, $birthdate_year, $phoneNumber, $mobileNumber, $addressline1, $addressline2, $addressline3, $stateprovince, $postcode, $closest_town, $error)
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
// if there are any errors, display them
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>"/>
<fieldset class="userdetails">
<legend>User Credentials</legend>
<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $user_id; ?></p>
<ul>
<li><label for="user_email">Email Address:</label><input name="user_email" maxlength="50" id="user_email" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>"><br></li>
<li><label for="user_pass">Your Password:</label><input name="user_pass" maxlength="50" id="user_pass" size="30" type="password" value="<?php echo $user_pass; ?>"><br></li>
<li><label for="user_pass_confirm">Password Again:</label><input name="user_pass_confirm" maxlength="50" id="user_pass_confirm" size="30" type="password" value="<?php echo $user_pass_confirm; ?>"><br></li>
<li><label for="user_username">Your Username:</label><input name="user_username" maxlength="50" id="user_username" size="30" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_username; ?>"></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Details</legend>
<ul>
<li><label for="firstname">First Name:</label><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="25" maxlength="200" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" /><br></li>
<li><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="25" maxlength="200" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" /><br></li>

<li><label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<select name="gender" id="gender">
<option selected="" value=""> </option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
<option value="unspecified">Unspecified</option>
</select><br></li>
<li><label for"birthdate_day">Date of birth:</label>
<select name="birthdate_day" id="birthdate_day">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="1st">1</option>
<option value="2nd">2</option>
<option value="3rd">3</option>
<option value="4th">4</option>
<option value="5th">5</option>
<option value="6th">6</option>
<option value="7th">7</option>
<option value="8th">8</option>
<option value="9th">9</option>
<option value="10th">10</option>
<option value="11th">11</option>
<option value="12th">12</option>
<option value="13th">13</option>
<option value="14th">14</option>
<option value="15th">15</option>
<option value="16th">16</option>
<option value="17th">17</option>
<option value="18th">18</option>
<option value="19th">19</option>
<option value="20th">20</option>
<option value="21st">21</option>
<option value="22nd">22</option>
<option value="23rd">23</option>
<option value="24th">24</option>
<option value="25th">25</option>
<option value="26th">26</option>
<option value="27th">27</option>
<option value="28th">28</option>
<option value="29th">29</option>
<option value="30th">30</option>
<option value="31st">31</option>

</select>
<select name="birthdate_month" id="birthdate_month">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>

</select><br></li>
<li><label for="birthdate_year">Birth Year:</label><input name="birthdate_year" type="number" maxlength="4" id="birthdate_year" size="4" value="<?php echo $birthdate_year; ?>"><br>
</li>

<li>
  <label for="phoneNumber">Home Phone:</label>
  <input name="phoneNumber" type="number" maxlength="9" id="phoneNumber" size="9" value="<?php echo $phoneNumber; ?>"><br></li>

<li><label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input name="mobileNumber" type="number" maxlength="11" id="mobileNumber" size="11" value="<?php echo $mobileNumber; ?>"><span class="informational">e.g: 0276123456</span><br></li>

<li><label for="addressline1">Street Address:</label>
<input name="addressline1" maxlength="100" id="addressline1" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo $addressline1; ?>"><br></li>
<li><label for="addressline2">Suburb:</label>
<input name="addressline2" maxlength="100" id="addressline2" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo $addressline2; ?>"><br></li>
<li><label for="addressline3">City:</label>
<input name="addressline3" maxlength="100" id="addressline3" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo $addressline3; ?>"><br></li>
        <li><label for="stateprovince">State/Province:</label>
<select name="stateprovince" id="stateprovince">
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $stateprovince; ?>"></option>
<option value="northland">Northland</option>
<option value="auckland">Auckland</option>
<option value="waikato">Waikato</option>
<option value="bayofplenty">Bay of Plenty</option>
<option value="eastcoast">East Coast</option>
<option value="hawkesbay">Hawkes Bay</option>
<option value="taranaki">Taranaki</option>
<option value="kingcountry">King Country</option>
<option value="wanganui">Wanganui</option>
<option value="manawatu">Manawatu</option>
<option value="wairarapa">Wairarapa</option>
<option value="wellington">Wellington</option>
<option value="nelsonbays">Nelson Bays</option>
<option value="marlborough">Marlborough</option>
<option value="buller">Buller</option>
<option value="westland">Westland</option>
<option value="northcanterbury">North Canterbury</option>
<option value="canterbury">Canterbury</option>
<option value="midcanterbury">Mid Canterbury</option>
<option value="southcanterbury">South Canterbury</option>
<option value="northotago">North Otago</option>
<option value="otago">Otago</option>
<option value="southland">Southland</option>
<option value="chathamisl">Chatham Islands</option>
</select><br></li>
<li><label for="postcode">Post Code:</label>
<input name="postcode" type="number" maxlength="4" id="postcode" size="4" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>"><span class="informational"><a href="http://www.nzpost.co.nz/nzpost/control/business/postcode_finder#post_code_finder" target="_blank" title="Find your post code (only for New Zealand)">Find your post code</a></span><br></li>
<li><label for="closest_town">Closest Town:</label>
<select name="closest_town" id="closest_town">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="dargaville">Northland - Dargaville</option>
<option value="kaikohe">Northland - Kaikohe</option>
<option value="kaitaia">Northland - Kaitaia</option>
<option value="kawakawa">Northland - Kawakawa</option>
<option value="kerikeri">Northland - Kerikeri</option>
<option value="maungaturoto">Northland - Maungaturoto</option>
<option value="paihia">Northland - Paihia</option>
<option value="whangarei">Northland - Whangarei</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="aucklandcity">Auckland - Auckland City</option>
<option value="franklin">Auckland - Franklin</option>
<option value="greatbarrierisland">Auckland - Great Barrier Island</option>
<option value="helensville">Auckland - Helensville</option>
<option value="hibiscuscoast">Auckland - Hibiscus Coast</option>
<option value="manukaucity">Auckland - Manukau City</option>
<option value="northshore">Auckland - North Shore</option>
<option value="papakuracity">Auckland - Papakura City</option>
<option value="waihekeisl">Auckland - Waiheke Island</option>
<option value="waitakerecity">Auckland - Waitakere City</option>
<option value="warkworth">Auckland - Warkworth</option>
<option value="wellsford">Auckland - Wellsford</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="cambridge">Waikato - Cambridge</option>
<option value="coromandel">Waikato - Coromandel</option>
<option value="hamilton">Waikato - Hamilton</option>
<option value="huntly">Waikato - Huntly</option>
<option value="matamata">Waikato - Matamata</option>
<option value="morrinsville">Waikato - Morrinsville</option>
<option value="otorohanga">Waikato - Otorohanga</option>
<option value="paeroa">Waikato - Paeroa</option>
<option value="raglan">Waikato - Raglan</option>
<option value="taumarunui">Waikato - Taumarunui</option>
<option value="teawamutu">Waikato - Te Awamutu</option>
<option value="tekuiti">Waikato - Te Kuiti</option>
<option value="thames">Waikato - Thames</option>
<option value="tokoroa_putaruru">Waikato - Tokoroa/Putaruru</option>
<option value="waihi">Waikato - Waihi</option>
<option value="waihi_beach">Waikato - Waihi Beach</option>
<option value="whangamata">Waikato - Whangamata</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="katikati">Bay of Plenty - Katikati</option>
<option value="mt_maunganui">Bay of Plenty - Mt. Maunganui</option>
<option value="opotiki">Bay of Plenty - Opotiki</option>
<option value="rotorua">Bay of Plenty - Rotorua</option>
<option value="taupo">Bay of Plenty - Taupo</option>
<option value="tauranga">Bay of Plenty - Tauranga</option>
<option value="te_puke">Bay of Plenty - Te Puke</option>
<option value="turangi">Bay of Plenty - Turangi</option>
<option value="whakatane">Bay of Plenty - Whakatane</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="gisborne">Gisborne - Gisborne</option>
<option value="ruatoria">Gisborne - Ruatoria</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="dannevirke">Hawkes Bay - Dannevirke</option>
<option value="hastings">Hawkes Bay - Hastings</option>
<option value="napier">Hawkes Bay - Napier</option>
<option value="waipukurau">Hawkes Bay - Waipukurau</option>
<option value="wairoa">Hawkes Bay - Wairoa</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="hawera">Taranaki - Hawera</option>
<option value="mokau">Taranaki - Mokau</option>
<option value="new_plymouth">Taranaki - New Plymouth</option>
<option value="opunake">Taranaki - Opunake</option>
<option value="stratford">Taranaki - Stratford</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="ohakune">Wanganui - Ohakune</option>
<option value="taihape">Wanganui - Taihape</option>
<option value="waiouru">Wanganui - Waiouru</option>
<option value="wanganui">Wanganui - Wanganui</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="bulls">Manawatu - Bulls</option>
<option value="fielding">Manawatu - Feilding</option>
<option value="levin">Manawatu - Levin</option>
<option value="manawatu">Manawatu - Manawatu</option>
<option value="marton">Manawatu - Marton</option>
<option value="palmerston_north">Manawatu - Palmerston North</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="carterton">Wairarapa - Carterton</option>
<option value="featherston">Wairarapa - Featherston</option>
<option value="greytown">Wairarapa - Greytown</option>
<option value="martinborough">Wairarapa - Martinborough</option>
<option value="masterton">Wairarapa - Masterton</option>
<option value="paihiatua">Wairarapa - Pahiatua</option>
<option value="woodville">Wairarapa - Woodville</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="kapiti">Wellington - Kapiti</option>
<option value="lower_hutt">Wellington - Lower Hutt City</option>
<option value="porirua">Wellington - Porirua</option>
<option value="upper_hutt">Wellington - Upper Hutt City</option>
<option value="wellington">Wellington - Wellington City</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="golden_bay">Nelson Bays - Golden Bay</option>
<option value="motueka">Nelson Bays - Motueka</option>
<option value="murchison">Nelson Bays - Murchison</option>
<option value="nelson">Nelson Bays - Nelson</option>
<option value="picton">Nelson Bays - Picton</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="blenheim">Marlborough - Blenheim</option>
<option value="marlborough_sounds">Marlborough - Marlborough Sounds</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="greymouth">West Coast - Greymouth</option>
<option value="hokitika">West Coast - Hokitika</option>
<option value="westport">West Coast - Westport</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="akaroa">Canterbury - Akaroa</option>
<option value="amberley">Canterbury - Amberley</option>
<option value="ashburton">Canterbury - Ashburton</option>
<option value="cheviot">Canterbury - Cheviot</option>
<option value="christchurch">Canterbury - Christchurch City</option>
<option value="darfield">Canterbury - Darfield</option>
<option value="fairlie">Canterbury - Fairlie</option>
<option value="geraldine">Canterbury - Geraldine</option>
<option value="hamnersprings">Canterbury - Hanmer Springs</option>
<option value="kaiapoi">Canterbury - Kaiapoi</option>
<option value="kaikoura">Canterbury - Kaikoura</option>
<option value="mtcook">Canterbury - Mt Cook</option>
<option value="rangiora">Canterbury - Rangiora</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="timaru_oamaru_kurow">Timaru - Oamaru - Kurow</option>
<option value="timaru_oamaru_oamaru">Timaru - Oamaru - Oamaru</option>
<option value="timaru_oamaru_timaru">Timaru - Oamaru - Timaru</option>
<option value="timaru_oamaru_twizel">Timaru - Oamaru - Twizel</option>
<option value="timaru_oamaru_waimate">Timaru - Oamaru - Waimate</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="alexandra">Otago - Alexandra</option>
<option value="balclutha">Otago - Balclutha</option>
<option value="cromwell">Otago - Cromwell</option>
<option value="dunedin">Otago - Dunedin</option>
<option value="lawrence">Otago - Lawrence</option>
<option value="milton">Otago - Milton</option>
<option value="palmerston">Otago - Palmerston</option>
<option value="queenstown">Otago - Queenstown</option>
<option value="ranfurly">Otago - Ranfurly</option>
<option value="roxburgh">Otago - Roxburgh</option>
<option value="wanaka">Otago - Wanaka</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="bluff">Southland - Bluff</option>
<option value="edendale">Southland - Edendale</option>
<option value="gore">Southland - Gore</option>
<option value="invercargill">Southland - Invercargill</option>
<option value="lumsden">Southland - Lumsden</option>
<option value="otautau">Southland - Otautau</option>
<option value="riverton">Southland - Riverton</option>
<option value="stewart_island">Southland - Stewart Island</option>
<option value="te_anau">Southland - Te Anau</option>
<option value="tokanui">Southland - Tokanui</option>
<option value="winton">Southland - Winton</option>
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="chathamisl">Chatham Islands</option>
</select><br></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form> 
</body>
</html> 
<?php
}

// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
if (is_numeric($_POST['user_id'])){
// get form data, making sure it is valid
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
$user_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_pass']);
$user_pass_confirm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_pass_confirm']);
$user_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_username']);
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);//optional field
$birthdate_day = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate_day']);
$birthdate_month = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate_month']);
$birthdate_year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate_year']);
$phoneNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phoneNumber']);
$mobileNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobileNumber']);
$addressline1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addressline1']);
$addressline2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addressline2']); // optional field
$addressline3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addressline3']);
$stateprovince = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stateprovince']); 
$postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']); // optional field
$closest_town = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['closest_town']); //optional field
$date = time();

// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $user_email =='' || $user_pass == '' || $user_pass_confirm == '' || $user_username == '' || $firstname =='' || $lastname == '' || $gender == '' || $birthdate_day == '' || $birthdate_month == '' || $birthdate_year == '' || $phoneNumber == '' || $mobileNumber == '' || $addressline1 == '' || $addressline2 == '' || $addressline3 == '' || $stateprovince == '' || $postcode == '' || $closest_town == ''){
// generate error message
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

//error, display form
renderForm($user_id, $user_email, $user_pass, $user_pass_confirm, $user_username, $firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthdate_day, $birthdate_month, $birthdate_year, $phoneNumber, $mobileNumber, $addressline1, $addressline2, $addressline3, $stateprovince, $postcode, $closest_town, $error);
}
else{
// save the data to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE user_list SET user_email='$user_email', user_pass=sha1('$user_pass.$salt'), user_pass_confirm=sha1('$user_pass_confirm.$salt'), user_username='$user_username', firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', gender='$gender', birthdate_day='$birthdate_day, birthdate_month='$birthdate_month', birthdate_year='$birthdate_year', phoneNumber='$phoneNumber', mobileNumber='$mobileNumber', addressline1='$addressline1', addressline2='$addressline2', addressline3='$addressline3', stateprovince='$stateprovince', postcode='$postcode', closest_town='$closest_town' WHERE user_id='$user_id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 

// once saved, redirect back to the view page
header("Location: itradeusers.php"); 
}
}
else
{
// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
echo 'Error! ID not valid.';
}
}
else
// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
{

// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['user_id']) && $_GET['user_id'] > 0)
{
// query db
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE user_id=$user_id")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{

// get data from db
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$user_email = $row['user_email'];
$user_pass = $row['user_pass'];
$user_pass_confirm = $row['user_pass_confirm'];
$user_username = $row['user_username'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$gender = $row['gender'];
$birthdate_day = $row['birthdate_day'];
$birthdate_month = $row['birthdate_month'];
$birthdate_year = $row['birthdate_year'];
$phoneNumber = $row['phoneNumber'];
$mobileNumber = $row['mobileNumber'];
$addressline1 = $row['addressline1'];
$addressline2 = $row['addressline2'];
$addressline3 = $row['addressline3'];
$stateprovince = $row['stateprovince'];
$postcode = $row['postcode'];
$closest_town = $row['closest_town'];

// show form
renderForm($user_id, $user_email, $user_pass, $user_pass_confirm, $user_username, $firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthdate_day, $birthdate_month, $birthdate_year, $phoneNumber, $mobileNumber, $addressline1, $addressline2, $addressline3, $stateprovince, $postcode, $closest_town, $error);
}else
// if no match, display result
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
{
echo 'Error! the \'id\' is not valid.';
}
}
?>
```

If someone could tell me what I have done wrong, or even explain to me a better way of doing something like this, please let me know... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well first I'll tell you what I am successfully doing... I can click on the link "<td><a href="delete.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Delete</a></td>" and that successfully deletes a user from the database. When I click on the "Edit" link, I am taken to a page that already has the user's details pre filled in the form, and I can alter them as neccessary (also, I am wanting to implement this for my users as well seperately). When I have edited any of the fields I click on Submit button and I get a pre-defined error message saying "'Error! ID not valid.". I can give you files if need be.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the `name` of your hidden input: You're calling `id`, but then looking for `$_POST['user_id']`. If you change those to match, does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you're storing passwords in plain text. That is a big no no!

For updating user info have a look at the `UPDATE` command for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

For the delete/block issue, you could add another column that stores the user status (deleted, blocked, active, etc). You could then check the status of this column when the user logs in or visits a page.

Comment: I'm just storing the passwords there for personal reference, this is on my portable server but once I upload it it will be changed for sure.